# Assuming MLM/Nauka is launched, what happens to MRM-1/Rassvet?

Tags: iss, planning, russian-segment

For the purposes of this question, assume Russia's [Multipurpose Laboratory Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nauka_(ISS_module)) (MLM/Nauka) gets launched and makes it to the ISS.

Most articles I read say the MLM will dock at the FGB's nadir port (for example, the confusingly written Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nauka_(ISS_module))) At first writing of this question, I thought the DC-1 had been discarded as planned. No, it hasn't. I find the whole situation very difficult to sort out.)

AFAIK the [Mini-Research Module 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rassvet_(ISS_module)) (MRM-1/Rassvet) is currently docked at the FGB nadir port. This NASA [rendering](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/visiting-vehicle-launches-arrivals-and-departures) from August 2019 shows it there (green arrow added by me).

[image]

What is the plan for MRM assuming the MLM is to replace it at the FGB nadir port?

Comment: I've added some links/names for the benefit of readers like me with limited space-word vocabulary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MLM is replacing the DC-1 docking compartment (Pirs).  Not Rassvet.  It is docking to Zvezda not Zarya.

Russian Space Web has an [excellent article](http://russianspaceweb.com/iss_fgb2.html) on the history of the MLM/Nauka/FGB-II module. This detail is included when it says:

> Prior to the MLM launch, the Docking Compartment-1, which had occupied the nadir (Earth-facing) docking port of the Zvezda service module, was to be discarded along with a departing Progress cargo ship. It would then be directed to the Earth atmosphere to burn up. The MLM would then use its own engines to rendezvous with the station and dock to the freed nadir port on Zvezda.

An attempt to match the picture in the question but with the DC replaced with MLM.  Rendering by [Organic Marble](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/6944/organic-marble) using DOUG visualization software.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense. I couldn't figure how the ERA and the airlock would get transferred from Rassvet to MLM in a dump-Rassvet scenario.

Comment: I edited to add a picture, please roll back if not welcome.

Comment: Just a note: ERA is on the Nauka MLM, the radiator and airlock are transferred, from their position on the Rassvet MRM-1, after the MLM has docked. ERA is used with a grapple extension on the Airlock since the ERA is too short at 11m. The ERA component on the MRM-1 is a spare elbow/limb part for the ERA.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the idea of MLM being docked to the bottom of Zarya FGB was a thing in the years 2004-2007. At that time MRM-1 Rassvet and MRM-2 Poisk didn't exist, and DC-1 Pirs was supposed to move to the side port of the Science Power Module (upgraded version of the SPP). This would allow the Russian Research Module RM (also known as IM) to dock to the bottom of Zvezda SM while MLM Nauka would be docked to the bottom port of FGB Zarya. Here's a picture of that configuration:

[image]

Sources:

- [capcomespace.net](http://www.capcomespace.net/dossiers/ISS/russie/elements_russie_03.htm);
- [bis-space.com](http://www.bis-space.com/belgium/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/theissrussiansegment.pdf).

Comment: Hello and welcome to Space SE. Could you perhaps add a reference to where you got the info (and image) from? You can edit it in using the "edit" link at the bottom of your answer.

Comment: Thanks, this adds some context, but a source would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @ISS_fan14 1) for people to be notified that you have replied to them in a comment, use the [@replies feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/303080) (see also [metaFAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/303080)). The reason you were notified without it originally is because you are the post author. 2) As mentioned in the first comment, please *edit your post* and add the source directly into your post. Question and Answer posts are editable and meant to be updated when needed, readers don't always read comments and comments can sometimes be unexpectedly deleted. *Thanks!*